# When I call method from Test I have Always null resolte

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have test class ExecuteTest and I want to test the method `returnString` method who is in `MyStringClass`, and in returnString I call `strings()` from class `OtherString`.

This is my code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExecuteTest  {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyStringClass myStringClass;

    @Mock
    private OtherString otherString;



    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testString() {
        String test = myStringClass.returnString("test");

        assertThat(test, equalTo(test));

    }

}



@Service
public class MyStringClass {

    @Autowired
    private OtherString otherString;



    public <T extends Object> T returnString(String key) {
        return (T) otherString.strings(key);

    }
}
```

And my test variable is always null in my test.

Comment: What would you expect in test variable?

Comment: I expect `String test = myStringClass.returnString("test"); `return String.

Comment: Which value you expect? You mocked your OtherString class(you tell "hey when I call methods on this class don't call normal methods but call one that I tell you") but later you didn't specified which class should be called. You should tell something like when(otherString.strings(any())).thenReturn("something");